# Access Denied Error while Use Google.api.auth in Azure Hosting

Tags: c#, azure, google-drive-api

I am using google drive API,google developer account i enabled this API and get credential like clientId,clientSecret.i m using code when i run application in consoleapplication is working fine,but when i Host code in my 
azure server it gives error like

**System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied\r\n   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()\r\n   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n**

i used same credential for production also

below code i used:
            string[] scopes1 = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, 
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };

```
        var clientId = "clientidfrom developergoogle";
        var clientSecret = "secretkeyfrom developergoogle";
        var credential1 = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
         scopes1,
        "Admin",
         CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Can someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: what's drive api doing in Azure?

Comment: we are retrieve files and create file using spreadsheet API and reading file

Comment: Could you please tell me which azure service you hosted this application? Azure VM or azure web job? As far as I know, this error occurs when the google login doesn't passed. It will not return a access token to your application.

Comment: It is just website service. Do I need any changes in  Google consol account

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the exception and specific this part. `LocalServerCodeReceiver`
It seems that the google code is trying to run a local server on a free port
see [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1LocalServerCodeReceiver) , to receive a verification code. But both the internal firewall and the azure network firewall will probably block this port. What you need is a way to specify the receiver port so that you can open this port in the firewalls.

The real reason for the access denied error is that HttpListener is using http.sys to bind a specific port to the listener. But because it is in non-admin port the binding is not allowed. This means you have to set the acl like this.

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user`

MyUri is the OAuth callback.

Comment: Thanks for response But where i need to specify Port/Free Port?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this example `Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)` https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth you still have to specify a callback but this time it will call your server on port 80 or 443. This still means you have to open up the firewall to allow inbound trafic.

Comment: I have tried but this solution for asp.net MVC Application and i have a Project WEBAPI so it not work